# How to distribute a DeskBand via the Windows Store

Tags: c#, c++, com, deskband

I have a Deskband DLL written in C++ that is registered via calling regsvr32 mydeskband.dll. The Deskband has a configuration app written in C#, that I can likely convert to a UWP app using the desktop app converter. As far as I know, there isn't a way to distribute DLL that requires registration via the Windows store.

My question is, what is the best way for me to distribute this entire package via the Windows Store? My thought is I might only distribute the configuration app via the Windows store and have the app link to an online download of the exe file for installing the Deskband DLL, but this is cumbersome and messy. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The Desktop App Converter and Windows 10 Creator's edition now supports out-of-proc COM servers. See [here.](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/04/13/com-server-ole-document-support-desktop-bridge)

Registration is done in the AppxManfest.xml file. Not all scenarios are supported, but its worth a try to see if this will work for you.

If so, you'll be able to distribute your extension through the Windows Store.

Comment: Awesome info, thanks. Unfortunately I think this still doesn't apply, as deskbands are in-process COM servers (dlls) rather than out-of-process servers (exes).